# C# How to avoid many params into class constructor ? Sorting collection by class field

Tags: c#, .net, class, sorting, constructor

For example I have a simple class Cinema:

```
public class Cinema
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Film_title { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public DateTime Cinema_start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime Cinema_end_date { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        public Cinema(string id, string film_title, string year, string country, string start, string end, string duration)
        {
            this.Id = int.Parse(id);
            this.Film_title = film_title;
            this.Year = int.Parse(year);
            this.Country = country;
            this.Cinema_start_date = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            this.Cinema_end_date = DateTime.ParseExact(end, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if ( this.Cinema_end_date < this.Cinema_start_date)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End rent lower than start rent ( Replaced )");
                DateTime tmp = this.Cinema_start_date;
                this.Cinema_start_date = this.Cinema_end_date;
                this.Cinema_end_date = tmp;
            }
            this.Duration = int.Parse(duration);
            
        }
   }
```

To create an instance of the class I do as follows:

```cs
// for example
string[] words = {"1, "Fast and furious", "USA", "2000-01-01", "2000-02-02", "85"};

Cinema tmp = new Cinema(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5], words[6]);
```

However, I want to create it as follows to avoid square brackets and binding to indexing:

```
Cinema tmp = new Cinema(words); // something like that
```

Also I want to avoid so many if blocks there:

```
if(type == "Id" || type == "Year" || type == "Duration")
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(cinema1.GetValue(cinema_c[i + 1])) < Convert.ToInt32(cinema1.GetValue(cinema_c[i])))
    {
        Cinema tmp = cinema_c[i + 1].deep_copy();
        cinema_c[i + 1] = cinema_c[i].deep_copy();
        cinema_c[i] = tmp.deep_copy();
    }
}
if (type == "Country" || type == "Film_title")
{
    StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
    if (comparer.Compare(((cinema1.GetValue(cinema_c[i + 1])).ToString()), ((cinema1.GetValue(cinema_c[i])).ToString())) < 0)
    {
        Cinema tmp = cinema_c[i + 1].deep_copy();
        cinema_c[i + 1] = cinema_c[i].deep_copy();
        cinema_c[i] = tmp.deep_copy();
    }
}
```

And so on...
I use this code to sort instances of a class by one of its attributes in the collection. I will be grateful if you suggest an alternative. Thank you.

Comment: It´s not clear what is the method `GetValue`. It looks like the sort iteration method you posted is an old implementation which receives an array of string attributes (cinema_c). If you had an array of `Cinema`, you could sort it just passing a `KeySelector` lambda to the `IEnumerable<> OrderBy` extension method.

Comment: It looks like you trying to deserialize a string representation of your object. There are lots of libraries for this purpose which save you all that trouble. Where are you getting those string values from? A CSV file maybe?

Comment: Use an [Object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers). See also [Init-only properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#init-only-properties).

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr It is build-in method and yes I use it for own bubble sort.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Why are you converting from typed data, to strings, back to typed data? This is slower and less accurate than just passing in the correct data types? Where is `words` coming from? You probably need to attack the problem there, not in your constructor.

Comment: @YuriiSmolii Is `cinema1` object a `DataReader`? What is it type?

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr It is reflection property.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method to avoid large number of arguments in the method and constructors is to create a type, like this

```
public class CinemaInfo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FilmTitle {get; set;}
    // more properties ....
}

var info = new CinemaInfo() { Id = 1, FilmTitle = "Tha film", .... };
Cinema cinema = new Cinema(info);
```

If you go passed about 6-7 arguments - create a type/class

Answer (score 0):

Change you constructor to this:

```
public class Cinema
{
.....

   public Cinema(string[] fields)
   {
            this.Id = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            this.Film_title = fields[1];
            this.Year = int.Parse(fields[2]);
           .... and so on
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah good way, but Is the way to avoid square brackets in all construct.?
Imagine we have 1000 params )

Comment: @YuriiSmolii If you have a class that needs 1000 params in the construct, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @YuriiSmolii also, how do you expect to convert an array of strings to a class without using indexing or having a parameter for each property?

Comment: My task is to create a constructor that does not depend on the amount of fields class.